# Program to transform a string in hexadecimal?

Tags: python, bash, python-3.x

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import sys

try:
    string=sys.argv[1]
    cmd = "echo -n "+string+" | xxd -ps | sed 's/[[:xdigit:]]\{2\}/\\\\x&/g'"
    os.system(cmd)
except IndexError:
    print("\nInforme a string!\n")
```

I found this code on Internet. I tried hard to understand what it does. Could someone explain?

```
string=sys.argv[1]
cmd = "echo -n "+string+" | xxd -ps | sed 's/[[:xdigit:]]\{2\}/\\\\x&/g'"
```

The two lines above are like magic to me.

Comment: What for? Could you explain it, please?

Comment: give an example of desired input and output

Comment: Side-note: This code is subject to serious issues from shell metacharacters in the (user provided) `string` which allow the user to execute arbitrary code and otherwise misbehave (usually not a big deal, since the program runs with the user's permissions, but if some idiot tagged the program with the setuid bit, it might have greater privileges than the user that could be exploited for malicious purposes). It's also not necessary, since Python can do the same work in Python, without external programs, and avoid the risk completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the line:

```
cmd = "echo -n "+string+" | xxd -ps | sed 's/[[:xdigit:]]\{2\}/\\\\x&/g'"
```

- `echo` sends the text to the standard output,
- `|` pipes that output to `xxd`, which translates binary to hexadecimal (think hex editors); the `-ps` flag, according to the `xxd` man page:

> ```
>    -p | -ps | -postscript | -plain
>           output  in  postscript  continuous  hexdump style. Also known as
>           plain hexdump style.
> ```

- `sed` is the stream editor command - there are literally books on this. Basically here, the piped hexdecimal output from the `xxd -ps` command has this replacement regex performed, broken down here:

  ```
  sed 's/          # Start find
  [[:xdigit]]\{2\} # Match two or more hexadecimal characters 
                   # ([[:xdigit:]] is POSIX-compliant representation 
                   # of hexadecimal character)
  /                # End find, start replace
  \\\\x&           # Lots of escaping backslashes - as \x&; the ampersand
                   # becomes the entire previous match  (the 2 hexadecimal
                   # characters), e.g. '\x8e'
  /g'              # End find, and g means all matches are changed
  ```

> \xxx
>       Produces or matches a character whose hexadecimal ascii value is xx. 
>   ([source](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Escapes.html))

- In a nutshell, the scripts takes an input and translates it to hexadecimal, and then the `sed` command converts them to ascii characters for each double of hexadecimal code characters from the `xxd` input.

Answer (score 1):

This code is meant to be executed from the command line. It takes the first argument passed to the script and spits out that string encoded in ASCII. Let's break down the shell `cmd` so we can understand how it manages this.

```
echo -n "+string+"
```

Takes the variable `string` (a.k.a. the first argument to the script) and outputs it, passing it along to the next command via a pipe. (`-n` stops a newline from being appended to the string.)

```
xxd -ps
```

Converts the string to a hexadecimal number. (The `-ps` is just to simplify the output to just the hexadecimal number by removing some additional information that is usually outputted.)

```
sed 's/[[:xdigit:]]\{2\}/\\\\x&/g'
```

Finally, the string, which is now a hexadecimal number, gets piped to `sed s/.../.../g` which globally replaces all occurrences of a regular expression between the first and second slashes with whatever is between the second and third slashes. In our case, that regular expression is two consecutive hexadecimal digits (i.e. `0-9`, `A-F`, or `a-f`). This `sed` command is being used to prepend `\x` to each pair of hexadecimal digits (`\\\\` gets translated to `\` in the output due to character escaping and the `&` signals that whatever is being replaced should be inserted at that point.) Hence, we end up with the string encoded in ASCII, which is finally outputted and printed.

Comment: The input is given as a command line argument to the Python script. That's what the [`sys.argv[1]`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv) part does.

Answer (score 1):

The explain is already done by @Nick Bull and @pzp, here I just want to say something about the implementation, it's trivial and can hardly satisfy the purpose.

The original code would fail if the string contains unbalanced quote(single quote or double quote).

And I suppose a snippet of python code to do it more safely:

```
def charHex(ch):
    return hex(ord(ch))[1:]

hexStr = ''.join(map(charHex, string))
```

Comment: I believe the original code was prefixing the `x` in each value with a backslash (so it looked like a bunch of `\xXX` escapes that are legal in Python string literals), which this does not do, and this code will misbehave for ASCII values with single hex digit representations (it will not pad with a zero). Changing `charHex` to `return r'\x{:02x}'.format(ord(ch))` would fix both issues.